# iOS Touch ID work flow is confusing

Tags: ios, touch-id

I'm writing an iOS application with multiuser login support. I observed GDrive application there I successfully enable Touch ID, it connected successfully with touch-id I added in Device Setting.

Then I added another Finger Touch-ID(other user) in Device Settings, and what I observed is GDrive allowing other Touch-ID too to access my GDrive account.

**Now my Question are:**

1. Is it possible to bind Touch-ID to Application ID ?
2. Is it possible to bind Touch-ID to Application-User-ID, in case of multi login support ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to bind a TouchID to an application or user.

iOS framework for TouchID only allows you to check if the use is authenticated.

Comment: Then what is use of Touch ID, if all added Finger Touch-ID can access my application ? Is this what the behaviour OR I'm missing anything ?

Comment: That is the idea, only the user whom's finger print is know can open your app. Thus if the user gives his unlocked device to some one they can not op your app.

Comment: No that should not be ...though I added finger touch-id at device level settings but I still didn't give all of them to access of app. At least added touch is have some binding with app&I'd. There are plenty of cases you can not notice will not be secure, biggest example I can see GDrive it self.

Comment: The Apple provided API for touch only allow you to check wether a finger print is know to the system. There is no per app checking, it is all system wide.

Comment: OK, is this same behaviour for Android too. I could not able to test same GDrive app as they do not have implementation. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can just authenticate user whose finger print stored in iOS device (that you can store from setting application). You can say `AppStore application` is example of it. you haven't any access more then authentication of stored finger prints in iOS device. So you can not bind touch id with your application.

Comment: OK, Thanks. But I'm not sure what is the use case except to get login fast. But it's clearly an security flaw in multi user support application scenario.